# Match CORS URLs with wildcards

Tags: java, regex

I need to match CORS urls that satisfy the following requirements:

> Schemes are 'http' and 'https'
>
> Localhost should be allowed.
>
> Host may have `-` character
>
> Can have a wildcard `*` for a whole subdomain or a trailing wildcard `*`.
>
> TLD part not optional
>
> Segments have a size restriction {1,63}

Allowed:

```
https://localhost.localdomain
http://127.0.0.1
http://*.example.com
http://my*.example.com
https://env-us.example.com
https://*.example.com
https://*.example.net
http://localhost (hardcoded to allow)
```

Not allowed:

```
https://www.test.012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789
https://012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789.com
http://m*y.example.com
http://*my.example.com
http://.example.com
http://example.com*
http://-.com
http://z-.com
https://my.best-example*.best-example*.com
http://127*.0.0.1
https://my.*.com
```

Comment: http: //my*.domain.com is private case of http: //*.domain.com so why not create a regular expression only when is forbidden and all the rest allowed?

Comment: @Jan - fixed the question

Comment: @usr2564301 added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:[-\w]*(?:\*(?=\.))?(?:\.[-\w]{1,63})+)$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xVKCQE/4/). Note, that `\w` already includes `\d`.

---

Broken down, this says:

```
^                      # start of the string
(?:https?://)?         # http:// or https://, optional
(?:[-\w]*(?:\*(?=\.))? # - or word characters, followed by a star and a dot
(?:\.[-\w]{1,63})+)    # host part
$                      # the end of the string
```

Comment: I forgot to add `-` character requirement in the host part.

Comment: looks good, unfortunately I had to update some of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

To modify your regex only slighty, you should place the matching for the star after the (now optional) matching for words/digits in the subdomain block:

```
^(https?://)?(([\w\d]+(-[\w\d]+)*)*\*?\.)*(\w+)((\.\w{2,63})?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

I made the following changes to your regex:

- `[\\w\\d]` changed to `\\w`. Word char (`\w`) includes also a digit (`\d`).
- `+` after `(-[\\w\\d]+)` changed to `*`. `-...` part in (sub-)domain name is optional.
- Then I added `\\*?` for the (optional) trailing star.

So, my regex, without doubled backslashes, looks like below:

```
^(https?://)?((\*|\w+(-\w+)*)\*?\.)*(\w+)((\.\w{2,63})?)$
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer and updated requirements the following regex works:

```
^(https?:\/\/)?(([12]?\d?\d(\.[1-2]?\d?\d){3})|(([a-zA-Z][-\w]{0,61}\w\*?)|(\*)){1}(\.[-\w]{1,63}?)*(\.[\w]{1,63}))$
```